# drop event not working angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm building upload component in angular 2 and i stumble into problem. `(drop)` event is not working. This is my implementation

```
<div
class="input-upload"
*ngIf="status != 'finished'"
(drop)="onDrop($event)"
(dragenter)="dragenter()"
(dragleave)="dragleave()"
(dragover)="dragover()"
[ngClass]="{'drag-over': dragOver | async}"
>

onDrop(event: any) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
console.log(event)
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? I even put non existing function in `(drop)` event and angular is not giving error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to call `event.preventDefault()` in `dragOver(event)` to inform the browser that the currently hovered element is a valid drop target.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop

Answer (score 3):

add this on your dragover and dragend

return false;

@He is already doing what you said

Comment: He is doing it in `onDrop` but not in `dragOver()`

Comment: Got it. Sorry did not see that. With this, he may still need to return false

Comment: [event.preventDefault() vs return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) Worth a read.

Comment: @Jared in Angular returning false is just calling `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the other answers I was able to get it to work, but I was a little confused on putting the pieces together. This is the working HTML and TypeScript as of Angular 15.

The HTML:

```
<div (drop)="dropHandler($event);" (dragover)="dragOver($event)">
<p>Drag one or more files to this <i>drop zone</i>.</p>
</div>
```

The TypeScript:

```
  dropHandler(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event)
  }
  
  dragOver(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
```